# AMPscript: Pull data extension row count

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I'm trying to use AMPscript to pull the number of rows (all rows, rather than matching to a specific variable) in a data extension and insert that variable into an email. However, the variable I'm using isn't being recognized. Why is that? How can I fix it?

```
%%[ 
var @rowCount 
set @rowCount = DataExtensionRowCount("DE_Name") 
]%%

%%=v(@rowcount)=%%
```

Comment: Do you receive an error? Is it located in the same business unit, shared or local?

Comment: If it is a shared DE, you will need to use the `ent.` prefix.  E.g. `ent.DE_Name`.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal way but you can add a field to your DE and set its default value as "1" to use LookupRows like:

```
LookupRows("DE_Name","NewField","1")
```

Then you can count all rows.